# Qt. Как "Разрешить растягивать" виджеты вместе с главным окном?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть такой текстовый редактор. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении размера главного окна во время работы приложения изменялся размер текстового поля, а боковая панель оставалась прежней.

Есть ли у QTextEdit свойство, позволяющее изменить его размер при растяжении главного окна прриложения? SetMinimumSize () работает некорректно, возможно из-за QGridLayout, но я не уверен.

```
#include "mainclass.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QFontComboBox>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QPushButton>

MainClass::MainClass(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent) 
{
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));
    QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));

    QGridLayout *QMLayout = new QGridLayout;

    QTextEdit *MainTextEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    MainTextEdit->setMinimumSize(300, 300);

    QGroupBox *SidePanel = new QGroupBox (this);
    SidePanel->setGeometry(300,0, 220,300);

    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;

    QGroupBox *groupFontBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Параметры"));

    QLabel *PLabel = new QLabel (this);
    PLabel->setText("Параметры");

    QSpinBox *FontsizeSpin = new QSpinBox (this);
    FontsizeSpin->setRange(8, 20);
    FontsizeSpin->setSuffix(" пт");
    FontsizeSpin->setSingleStep(2);

    QLabel *FLabel = new QLabel (this);
    FLabel->setText("Шрифт");

    QFontComboBox *FStyleList = new QFontComboBox(this);

    vbox->addWidget(PLabel);
    vbox->addWidget(FLabel);
    vbox->addWidget(FStyleList);


    QLabel *SLabel = new QLabel(this);
    SLabel->setText("Размер");
    vbox->addWidget(SLabel);
    vbox->addWidget(FontsizeSpin);

    QLabel *FSLabel = new QLabel (this);
    FSLabel->setText("Начертание");
    vbox->addWidget(FSLabel);

    QCheckBox *ItalyStyle = new QCheckBox;
    ItalyStyle->setText("Курсив");

    QCheckBox *BoldStyle = new QCheckBox;
    BoldStyle->setText("Полужирный");

    QCheckBox *UnderLineStyle = new QCheckBox;
    UnderLineStyle->setText("Подчеркнутый");

    vbox->addWidget(ItalyStyle);
    vbox->addWidget(BoldStyle);
    vbox->addWidget(UnderLineStyle);

    QHBoxLayout *BLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QGroupBox *ButtonGroup = new QGroupBox;
    ButtonGroup->setLayout(BLayout);
    vbox->addWidget(ButtonGroup);

    QPushButton *QuitButton = new QPushButton("Выход");
    BLayout->addWidget(QuitButton);

    QPushButton *SaveButton = new QPushButton("Сохранить");
    BLayout->addWidget(SaveButton);

    groupFontBox->setLayout(vbox);
    SidePanel->setLayout(vbox);

    QMLayout->addWidget(MainTextEdit, 0, 0, 3, 3);
    QMLayout->addWidget(SidePanel, 1, 0,1,1);

    this->setLayout(QMLayout);
}

MainClass::~MainClass()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая функция у всех виджетов:

```
void QWidget::setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy horizontal, QSizePolicy::Policy vertical)
```

Для решения вашей проблемы используйте ее вместо setMinimumSize:

```
QTextEdit *MainTextEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
MainTextEdit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

Таким образом MainTextEdit расширится на всю ячейку в QGridLayout